in Dialogflow cx suggestions chips options's agent message are not showing after adding anchor in chips?
hi this is my default welcome intent custom payload
`{

  "richContent": [     [       {         "type": "chips",         "options": [           {             "value": "Price_list",             "text": "Price List",             "anchor": {               "target": "_self",               "href": "example.net/#/price_list"             }           },           {             "value": "Products_lists",             "text": "Products Lists",             "anchor": {               "href": "example.net/#/products_lists",               "target": "_self"             }           },           {             "text": "Something Else",             "value": "SOMETHING_ELSE"           }         ]       }     ]   ] }
The problem is I have created route Price_list and  intent Price_list which training phrase word is Price List and by clicking on Price List it only redirecting to https://example.net/#/price_list

and not showing the agent message of  Price_list route and intent

So redirect is working but I want to also show agent message based on training phrase and route.

